# Ignore a script in git checkout

Tags: git

I have script that takes 2 git commits run some steps to produce some output and compare the outputs.
For example:

```
git checkout <left_git_commit>
left_output = do_stuff()
git checkout <right_git_commit>
right_output = do_stuff()
compare_output(left_output, right_output)
```

I want to be able to change the script without committing it to change the output before compare.
for example:

```
git checkout <left_git_commit>
left_output = do_stuff()
git checkout <right_git_commit>
right_output = do_stuff()
left_output_transformed = transform(left_output)
right_output_transformed = transform(right_output)
compare_output(left_output_transformed, right_output_transformed)
```

If i do not commit the script i get the following error from git:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        some_script
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

Is there an elegant way around it without stashing/unstashing the script?

Comment: You could keep the script outside the repository.

Comment: That will work, but i want it to be in the repository so other people can use /modify it. Currently i workaround the issue by copying it and then changing it, i was wondering if there is a more elegant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking to do is basically find some way to ignore changes to a tracked file in Git, and Git doesn't provide any way to do that.  There are several reasons for that:

- If you did a checkout, Git would need to intuit whether your changes are precious and should be kept, or whether they're ephemeral and can be destroyed.
- If your changes were precious and Git checked out everything but your changes, then your working tree state would be inconsistent with the checkout, which could lead you to committing wrong data and would in any event be confusing.

Because different people want different things in this case and there's no right answer, Git opts to preserve your changes (to avoid data loss) and ask you to make a decision.  People commonly suggest the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits, but these are not designed for this and the [documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/de93cc14ab7e8db7645d8dbe4fd2603f76d5851f/Documentation/git-update-index.txt#L552-L566) recommends against this.

Your best options in this case are probably to stash before changing or to copy the script.  You could create an alias to stash, check out a branch, and then unstash if this is something you do frequently.